# Inverter dc to ac

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, inverter, dc-ac

I want to controll electronics made for AC with DC. In the specs it says 60 volt AC and 5W. Is it possible to use an inverter for translating 60 vdc to 60 vac? Or how can I calculate this? My idea is to simply put an inverter between but since I am pretty new to AC I am not sure if it would be that simple. So for example if I lower the vdc will that also lower the ac in a linear way?

Comment: Bear in mind that 60V AC is around 85V (65 x √2) peak voltage.  So there will need to be some degree of voltage step-up.

Comment: The usual method is an complementary oscillator with a step up voltage ratio using centre tapped DCwith a source resistance about 1% of load using watts

Answer (score 2):

To convert a DC voltage to AC requires that you implement an inverter that utilizes switching to vary current passing through an inductor and generate an an alternating voltage waveform. There is ample material online explaining the different techniques to do this.

Note some key factors you need to think when you choose what type of inverter could fit the job.

1. Know exactly what peak/RMS voltage do you plan to obtain.
2. What is maximum power you need from the inverter's output.
3. What quality of sine wave would work for you. In other words what is the amount of Harmonic distortion you can afford. That would translate to whether you need a pure sine wave inverter or a more basic square wave inverter.
4. Do you need isolation between the DC and AC circuits. Typically this is required but the inverter design will depend greatly on this.

With that being said, the good news is, you can even convert 2V DC to 60v AC. This is because during stages of inversion you can set the switching circuit's duty cycle/transformer ratio to obtain the voltage of your choice.

So study the points mentioned above online and then choose if you wish to design an inverter(which is going to need quite some understanding of power electronics) or but an inverter off the shelf.